# extrapolation to $\infty $ without knowing the exponent

Tags: numerical-methods, extrapolation

I obtained a curve numerically (see below). Apparently, the curve will converge to some value at $\infty $. How can I extract this limit value? The problem is that I do not know how this curve converges. It seems to be a power law. But I do not know the exponent.

By the way, I am sure it will converge. Actually, it is bounded by 1.

I get the curve in simulating some physical problem. It is actually some optimization process.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried plotting it using a logarithmic scale for the $y$-axis?

Comment: I do not think that is useful.

Comment: $y = b^x$ will turn into $\ln y = \ln(b) x$ revealing $b$. Or what did you mean by power law?

Comment: If you don't have anything more concrete than a graph, then it is impossible to see whether it converges. First off, it might start behaving like crazy at step 1000, or at 1000000, or even further out. Second, just because it _looks_ like it's converging, doesn't mean it actually does. It might still be growing, just at a pace too slow for us to see. Even if you know that it does converge, for these same reasons, you can't _at all_ tell what it converges to, at least not if you want to be correct about it.

Comment: What's the source of the data? If it's a computer program, you may get insight from analyzing the algorithm. If you're simulating some process, you may get insight from a description of the process (without looking at the code for the algorithm). You can probably get a better bound than $1$. And I do think graphing the logarithm may help. So if you want more help, edit the question to post as much background information as you can.

Comment: Consider using Richardson extrapolation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation).

Comment: Since you don't know the rate of convergence, in general, it will be a difficult problem to find the limit. You will have to do a lot computation and data analysis. There is no general formula without assumptions. Richardson extrapolation depends on an assumption about rate of convergence, for example. Your curve doesn't seem to satisfy that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always less than 1,
try plotting
$1/(1-f)$
or
$\log(1-f)$
and see what it looks like.

Comment: Actually it cannot be larger than 0.35 in this case.